# Parenthetical commas and foreign English

Tags: british-english, commas, subcontinental-english, australian-english

I advise a friend on her writing, despite not quite knowing an adverb from a proverb (kidding *(kinda)*).

Invariably, parenthetical commas such as the following:

> Jane, my assistant, opened the door.

are written as:

> Jane, my assistant opened the door.

Is there some foreign grammar she is drawing from, where this is common? Australian English or British English perhaps?

Comment: Just as a side note, this is called an appositive, or an apposition

Comment: @AndyPerfect, thanks! It isn't the root of the problem (two commas, or none, but not one), but explains when it might be correct to use no commas :http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28965/6297

Comment: It's not something that's common in British English.

Answer (score 1):

From Larry Trask's ['Guide to Punctuation'](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node13.html#SECTION00044000000000000000):

> The rule is this: a **pair** of bracketing commas is used to mark off a
>   weak interruption of the sentence — that is, an interruption which
>   does not disturb the smooth flow of the sentence.

That's what's required here: a pair of commas, not just one. This is not a matter of grammar, but of typographic convention.